# Can we get prior value of Parent record in process builder with child as the object?

Tags: process-builder, chatter, visual-workflow, master-detail

I have a list of salesforce task copied as records in an object called AdmissionSteps.

I have another object called Student.  I have created a process builder with AdmissionSteps as the object.

In the Student object there is a field called stage with values: started, paused, ongoing, completed.

In the AdmissionSteps object, there is a field called reason(text) and status. Status has 3 values: Yes, Wait, No.

I have a criteria called Post to chatter, with two conditions and for that:
 1. AdmissionSteps status field should be wait.
 2. Student stage field should be paused.

When admissionStep is in wait status then Student will be in Paused stage and at that time a message should be posted to chatter saying, student is in paused status with the value of reason field.
Later, If admissionStep status is changed to Yes, then student stage will be in ongoing.

My approach:
 1. I tried to use process builder with Student as the main object. But in the Post to Chatter Action, because i could not get AdmissionSteps(child) reason field posted to chatter, I skipped this approach.

2. I used process builder with AdmissionSteps as object. The criteria condition is (if status is Wait), then go to action and invoke a flow. The flow sends a chatter post under Parent record.

   In the second approach, i want to try  two more conditions in criteria condition and they are (if stage is IsChanged(Stage field) and if stage is ongoing then post to chatter).
   When i combine these condition with approach 2, then no message is post to chatter.

So, how do i get priorValue of a parent record field in process builder with child as the object.
Ofcourse, i tried to use, isChanged(ChildObject.ParentObject.Stage) field and ChildObject.ParentObject.Stage = 'Ongoing', but this did not work.

Looks like, i cannot go second level(parent level) deep in process builder.

Comment: As your process builder is built on AdmissionSteps( second approach ), you can use IsChanged() function to track changes on AdmissionSteps object only. If there is change in Students stage you can think of writing another process builder on "Students" object to post to chatter.

Comment: Have you tried a formula field on the child record and using PRIORVALUE against that formula text field?